# SwiftUI - Passing Dynamic Data via Button

Tags: state, swiftui, bindable

I'm trying to pass dynamic details from a master page to a detail page via a Button action. The view I'm passing to, I'm animating from off-screen, into the view using animation. I was able to get this to work when I was passing simple hard coded data, but I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to get it to pass data specific to the item row that was tapped.

I've wrapped the item row element with the button, but not sure I'm passing the right info into the button action parameter.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchView: View {
@State var show = false
var course = courseData
var body: some View {

    ZStack {

        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

            VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                ForEach(course) { item in
                    Button(action: { self.show.toggle() })  {
                        CourseResultTile(perks: item.perks, hotdeals: item.hotdeals, image: item.image, courseName: item.courseName, distance: item.distance, reviews: item.reviews, priceSpan: item.priceSpan, timeSpan: item.timeSpan)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.offset(y: 120)
```

// View I'm animating in below //

```
        FacilityView(show: $show, perks: self.perks, image: self.image, courseName: self.courseName, address: self.address)
            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: show ? 0 : 60), axis: (x: 0, y: 10.0, z: 0))
            .animation(.default)
            .offset(x: show ? 0 : -UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.show.toggle()
        }

    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Search"), displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)



}
}
```

// Course Data Model //

```
struct Course : Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var hotdeals: String
var perks: String
var image: String
var courseName: String
var distance: String
var reviews: String
var priceSpan: String
var timeSpan: String
var address: String
}

let courseData = [
Course(hotdeals: "Badge_HotDeals", perks: "Badge_NoPerks", image: "Image_CourseBackground", courseName: "Timacuan Golf Club", distance: "16.8 miles", reviews: "(562)", priceSpan: "$12.00 - $34.00", timeSpan: "1:53PM - 6:00 PM", address: "550 Timacuan Boulevard, Lake Mary, Florida, 32746"),
Course(hotdeals: "Badge_HotDeals", perks: "Badge_NoPerks", image: "Image_Course1", courseName: "Sanctuary Ridge Golf Club", distance: "20.1 miles", reviews: "(895)", priceSpan: "$12.00 - $34.95", timeSpan: "8:46 AM - 5:02 PM", address: "2601 Diamond Club Drive, Clermont, Florida, 34711"),
Course(hotdeals: "Badge_HotDeals", perks: "Badge_NoPerks", image: "Image_Course2", courseName: "Eagle Creek Golf Club - FL", distance: "14.3 miles", reviews: "(1K)", priceSpan: "$12.00 - $42.00", timeSpan: "8:42 AM - 5:51 PM", address: "10350 Emerson Lake Blvd, Orlando, Florida, 32832")
```

// FacilityView excerpt //

```
import SwiftUI

struct FacilityView: View {

var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
return formatter
}


var perks = "Badge_NoPerks"
var image = "Image_Course6"
var courseName = "Panther Lake: Orange County National"
var address = "16301 Phil Ritson Way, Winter Garden, FL 34787"
var holes = "18"
var par = "72"
var length = "6836"
var slope = "127"

@Binding var show: Bool
@State private var todaysDate = Date()
```

The error I'm getting is "Value of type 'SearchView' has no member 'variable I'm trying to pass'

Comment: Hi Jason, could you format your code better? it seems that you are missing something

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to throw the entire code into the question. But I'll update it.

Comment: Don't worry! Anyway I suggest you to pass the entire course to the FacilityView instead of using that long parameters list

Comment: Quick thought... have you looked into making your course data `ObjectObservable`?  I think it should be pretty straightforward doing it that way - it's the best way to pass things (in general) between views.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm just a UX Designer, so Swift/SwiftUI is still a learning process for me.